# Trying to increase numbers in lists

Tags: python

So when the input is for example 1, the first 0 in the list is supposed to increase to 1 and when the other output is 1 again the first number in the list which should then be 1 because it changed, should change to 2 but I really don't know how to do it I searched but I couldn't find an answer so please help.

edit: I removed the code that I think you don't need to know for this question so if you need to know something just tell me. These numbers can be chosen for a:1,2,3,4,5,6,7

```
used = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]


a = int(input("Choose a column."))
gb = used[a-1]=1
choose_r(a) 
gb


a = int(input("Choose a column."))
choose_g(a)
gb
```

Comment: How is you code related to the question?

Comment: I don't know exactly how to tell you but it's mainly from a=int(input("Kies een kolom.")) all the way in the bottom and the array is on top.

Comment: Please remove any code that isn't required for this specific question so that we know what to focus on.

Comment: Please take a look at how to create a [MCVE].  Also, at this point it is rather unclear what you are asking.  Please try your best to explain your problem, the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: `if (1 >= a <= 7): gebruikt[a-1] += 1`?

Comment: For example when both outputs are 1 the first 0 in gebruikt is supposed to increase to number 2. I'm sorry for my bad english but I really tried to make my question as clear as possible.

Comment: When should the other numbers in the list change?

Comment: Also "So when the input is for example 1, the first 0 in the list is supposed to increase to 1"... So when the input is 5, should the first 0 in the list increase to 5?

Comment: No when the output is 5 the fifth 0 in the list is supposed to increase by 1

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines directly below the second input:

```
if (1 >= a <= 7): 
    gebruikt[a-1] += 1
else:
    print ("Invalid Index Number")
```

Comment: This can also be defined as a function to be called after each input instead.